Is the Schwarzschild singularity a limit of the Kerr singularity?
In a Schwarzschild black hole, the singularity is spacelike. In a Kerr black hole, it is timelike.
Is there any continuous transformation between those solutions? Can the Schwarzschild solution be obtained by taking the Kerr solution in zero angular momentum limit?
Clarification: By "solution", I am mostly interested in behavior of the singularity. Is there a continuous transition from spacelike to timelike singularity?

Take equation (1) of the Wikipedia page on Kerr (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) and set $a=0$ to reproduce the Schwarzschild metric. $a$ is related to the angular momentum via $a=J/M$ (equation 6) so setting $a=0$ is the same as setting $J=0$.

Does this answer your question? Is the Schwarzschild black hole solution a special case of the Kerr solution?

I don't think this is a duplicate. The question is not asking whether the Schwarzschild solution is the zero rotation limit of the Kerr metric. It is specifically asking how the two singularities evolve into each other. That is not discussed in the proposed duplicate

Friendly reminder: don't use comments to post brief answers.

Related.

There is a continuous transformation of these two solutions, but it's an analytical one. You should look for Newman-Janis algorithm

The Kerr singularity is obtained when $ \Sigma=r^2+a^2\cos^2\theta=0 $ which means $ r=0 $ and $ \theta=\frac{\pi}{2} $.
In Cartesian coordinates, this leads to a ring in the equatorial plane with a radius equal to $ a $.
For a Schwarzschild black hole, you have $ a = 0 $  (no spin). Then the Kerr singularity becomes the center of the black hole ($ r = 0 $ with a zero radius ring) which is the Schwarzschild singularity.
Regarding your question related to the spacelike Schwarzschild singularity or the timelike Kerr singularity, I do not follow you because in the two cases the metric tensors are not defined since $ r=0 $ or $ \Sigma=0 $. In my opinion, the scalar products then can not be calculated and consequently the type of these singularities can not be determined.
Hoping to have answered your questions,
Best regards.

You are right that the metric tensor is not defined at the singularity, but the question could be answered in the limit approaching the singularity.

In Boyer-Lindquist coordinates, the Kerr metric is
$$ds^2=-\frac{\Delta}{\rho^2} \left(dt-a \sin^2{\theta}~d\phi\right)^2+\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{\rho^2}\left(\left(r^2+a^2\right)d\phi-a dt\right)^2+\frac{\rho^2}{\Delta} dr^2+ \rho^2 d\theta^2,~~~~\rightarrow(1)$$
where, $$\Delta(r)\equiv r^2-2Mr+a^2,~~~~\rightarrow(2)$$ $$\rho^2(r,\theta)\equiv r^2+a^2 \cos^2{\theta}.~~~~\rightarrow(3)$$
A curvature singularity occurs when $\rho^2=0$, which corresponds to a ring on the equatorial plane, $$r=0,~~~~\cos{\theta}=0.~~~~\rightarrow(4)$$
To judge the nature of the singularity, which is a surface of the form $\rho=\mathrm{const.}$, let us modify the coordinate system such that we have a coordinate $\rho$ instead of $r$.
Start with
$$d\rho=\partial_\mu \rho~dx^\mu,~~~~\rightarrow(5)$$
where, using Eq.(3), $$\partial_\mu \rho=\left(0,\frac{r}{\rho},\frac{-a^2\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{\rho},0\right).~~~~\rightarrow(6)$$
Then, substituiting Eq.(6) into Eq.(5), we get $$d\rho=\frac{1}{\rho}\left(rdr-a^2 \cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}d\theta\right).~~~~\rightarrow(7)$$
which could be written as
$$\color{red}{\rho dr}=\frac{\rho}{r}\left(\rho d\rho-a^2\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}d\theta\right).~~~~\rightarrow(8)$$
Now, substitute Eq.(8) into the original metric Eq.(1) to express the Kerr metric in coordinates $\{t,\rho,\theta,\phi\}$:
$$ds^2=-\frac{\Delta}{\rho^2} \left(dt-a \sin^2{\theta}~d\phi\right)^2+\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{\rho^2}\left(\left(r^2+a^2\right)d\phi-a dt\right)^2+\frac{\color{red}{\frac{\rho^2}{r^2}\left(\rho d\rho-a^2\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}d\theta\right)^2}}{\Delta}+ \rho^2 d\theta^2,~~~~\rightarrow(9)$$
where now $$r=r(\rho,\theta)=\sqrt{\rho^2-a^2\cos^2{\theta}},~~~~\rightarrow(10)$$ and $$\Delta(r)=\Delta\left(r\left(\rho,\theta\right)\right)=\rho^2-a^2\cos^2{\theta}-2M\sqrt{\rho^2-a^2\cos^2{\theta}}+a^2.~~~~\rightarrow(11)$$
Since we only care about the nature of the $\rho$ coordinate as we approach the singularity, let us set $t=t_0,~\theta=\pi/2,~\phi=\phi_0.$ The metric then becomes
$$ds^2=\frac{\frac{\rho^2}{r^2}\left(\rho d\rho\right)^2}{\Delta}=\left(\frac{\rho^2}{\rho^2-2M\rho+a^2}\right) d\rho^2.~~~~\rightarrow(12)$$
As you approach the singularity, $\rho$ gets closer and closer to zero, and $a^2$ dominates in the denominator:
$$ds^2\approx\left(\frac{\rho^2}{a^2}\right) d\rho^2>0 \Longrightarrow \boxed{\lim_{\rho\rightarrow0}{ds^2\big|_\left\{t=t_0,~\theta=\pi/2,~\phi=\phi_0\right\}}>0.}~~~~\rightarrow(13)$$
This shows that the coordinate $\rho$ is a spatial coordinate all the way down to the singularity.
If, however, we let $a\rightarrow0$ to get the Schwarzschild limit, then we recover the usual behavior of Schwarzschild: $\rho$ (which is identical to $r$ when $a=0$) becomes timelike below the horizon and all the way down to the singularity. We have
$$ds^2=\left(\frac{\rho^2}{\rho^2-2M\rho}\right) d\rho^2=\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho-2M}\right) d\rho^2\Longrightarrow\boxed{\lim_{\rho\rightarrow0}{ds^2\big|_\left\{\color{red}{a=0},~t=t_0,~\theta=\pi/2,~\phi=\phi_0\right\}}<0.}~~~~\rightarrow(14)$$
Equation (14) is the limit of equation (13) as $a\rightarrow0$ in the manner you asked for.

Instead of ~~~~\rightarrow(5) etc. you can just use \tag{5} to get a correctly placed equation number.
